# Uploaded video on YouTube does not appear on my channel

Tags: youtube

I uploaded a video today on YouTube and when I click on the link on my site to YouTube, it says: `this channel does not have any videos`. How do I get my videos to show in my channel for people that are visiting my YouTube account from my website?

Comment: Maybe you have it set to unlisted.

Answer (score 1):

It may take a while for the video to upload, especially if it has a large amount of data to cover.

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing your channel from another account then you probably should open your channel then go to *My Channel* option then click *Video Manger* at the top of your profile header then click edit on the video, you will be able to choose the right choice under the Basic Info option:

- Public = all people can see it
- Unlisted = Only people with the link can see it
- Private = Only you can see the video